# Paypal - make "Join Paypal" - optional in sandbox

Tags: paypal, option-type

I've started using PayPal sandbox.

When checking out, PayPal forces the user to join PayPal.

When I'm not using Sandbox, The "(Optional) Join PayPal for faster future checkout" is available.

I know how to enable this feature in a regular account, but how do I enable it in Sandbox mode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Log into the sandbox account and make sure PayPal Account Optional is enabled in the profile under Payment Receiving Preferences.